# HTTP Post Request - Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xmlhttprequest, http-post

I'm trying to perform a HTTP Post request proceeding like this :

```
public string DirectLinkPostResponse(string url, string parameters)
        {
            var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(parameters);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;

            using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())//here's where the error is raised
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }

            var response = request.GetResponse();

            if (response.GetResponseStream() == null)
                return null;

            var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

            return responseString;
        }
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error message :

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond XXX.XX.XX.XX:443

The thing is, when I'm redirecting the user to the url (with parameters), the page is well displayed, with an XML result. Is there something I'm missing ?

Comment: Did you try setting property request.AllowAutoRedirect as true?

Comment: Sorry but I don't see where to set this property...

Comment: Use following code:

HttpWebRequest request=(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url); 
request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections=1;
request.AllowAutoRedirect=true;

Comment: I've still got the same error...

Comment: Can it be related to https? Try adding:

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

before GetRequestStream()

Comment: Should I add that in my method, before creating anything ?

Comment: Yes, add it before making the request

Comment: Yeah well, still the same error...

Comment: Try adding following in .config file:

<system.net> 
    <defaultProxy> 
            <proxy usesystemdefault = "false" proxyaddress="http://address:port" bypassonlocal="false"/> 
    </defaultProxy> 
</system.net>

Comment: I'm sorry but still facing the same issue

Comment: I think you'll have to compare both requests using Fiddler and see if anything specific is missing from your request.

Comment: for dev, you can try to skip the SSLCeritificate check to see if the certificate validation check fails for this request.

Comment: @Saravanan how can I do that ?

Comment: you can try like the below `  ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(
            Object obj, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, 
            SslPolicyErrors errors)
            {
                return (true);
            };
`